# How to open the Network Manager?

Tags: network-manager

Can tell me how to open network manager in Ubuntu 12.04. It is a default package in Ubuntu OS, or we need to download it?

Answer (score 3):

Network Manager is by default present in Ubuntu

To open it

1) Click on the network icon you will find in top right corner of the screen you will see a drop down list like as shown:

[image: DropDown]

Click on the option of `Edit Connections..`

2) A new window will pop showing the different kinds of connection from there you can configure your network manually.

[image: Network Manager]

Comment: This not longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Of course Ubuntu have a network manager installed by default. It's enough to press <kbd>[Super](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_%28keyboard_button%29#Linux_and_BSD)</kbd> key and type only `net`:

[image: network manager]

You can also open it if you go to **System Settings...** → **Network**.

Or, you can open it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) using the following command:

```
gnome-control-center network
```

---

[image: network manager]

Comment: Actually i need to connect internet through network manager bacause i am using reliance netconnect i cant download any packages so i need to open network manager can u please tell me wat i want to do to connect internet by reliance netconnect modem.Thanks for ur valuable reply.